# One-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

if i have a relation like that: `1 - 0..1`, it is considered a one-to-many?

the only options that i have in mysql workbench are:

```
 1:1, 1:n, n:n...
```

thanks!

Comment: One to One relationship in a database can be achieved by implementing a unique constraint on FK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is a 1:1 (one-to-one) relationship. It's just that there isn't always another one that relates to the first one :)